# Imposing a restriction on a piecewise model to ensure continuity in R

Tags: r, piecewise

I have the following fitted model w/o restriction:

```
reg <- lm(y ~ indi_x + x + inter)
```

where `indi_x` = indicator variable for x > 14 and `inter` = interaction variable for indi_x and x.

I want to impose the restriction that indi_x + (inter * 14) = 0 to fit the two segments at x = 14. I've been using the `I()` function within `lm` but am not getting the output I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two slopes that are joined at `x = 14`, and you want to infer the individual slopes (and possibly the common intercept?)

This would do it:

```
reg <- lm(y ~ 1 + x + x : I(x > 14))
```

Note that `x * I(x > 14)` is now the *change* in slope. So the absolute slope of the second segment is `slope_2 - slope_1`.

Comment: This is close to the output I have in SAS. In my unrestricted model, the two segments were disconnected at x = 14 so I want to impose a restriction to force the segments together at x = 14. What does the 1 indicate in the `lm` function?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer to `x : I(x > 14)` instead of `x * I(x > 14)`. This "forces" only the slope to change at `x = 14`. The 1 is an intercept. So `y ~ 0 + x + x : I(x > 14)` is "forced" to start at the origin `(x = 0, y = 0)` while the model above can start at any `y` at `x = 0`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not doing it either.